# Is there there a way to download media from any android app

Tags: root-access, downloading, xposed-framework, android-pc, url

I'm not talking about popular applications like Youtube, Facebook or Instagram...

Let's say there's an android app called 'bla' and there are videos in it just like youtube and not showing the url...

What I'm asking is... Is there any way to download these videos directly from the app(using an xposed module or wtever..) or to find the urls of the videos(so I can download them from pc)...

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: No need for root even if you can export files directly from the app. Some helpers for that would be [Save a copy](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/app.rikka.savecopy), [Phone Saver](https://f-droid.org/packages/link.standen.michael.phonesaver/) or [Send to SD card](https://f-droid.org/packages/ru.gelin.android.sendtosd/).

Comment: If the app is a streaming app without download (offline) function then videos are never saved as file and thus can not be retrieved by apps mentioned by Izzy. For streaming apps there is no universal way.

Comment: In addition to what Robert said, if the app is using encryption on media files then the files are useless to the user.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying... yeah its a streaming app☹️... is there any way to get the streaming link even.. then I can try something from pc.. I tried using packet capture to grab the streaming link... But the problem is packet capture use vpn and this app doesnt allow ips from other countries I guess(It's not opening when packet capture is running)... Please let me know.. if somebody knows a trick to get the link..